# I have a cell of numbers, which is a subset of a larger set, can I group the missing ones together MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Imagine I have a set of numbers in the following form,

```
aa = {[1 2 3 4 5],[1 2 3 4 5], [1 2 3 4 5]};
bb = {[1 2 3],[1 3 4 5], [5]};
```

If I have aa and bb can I get a new variable cc,

```
cc = {[4 5],[2],[1 2 3 4]}
```

Automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Together use `cellfun` to operate on each member of the arrays, and use `setdiff` to generate the the differences:

```
aa = {[1 2 3 4 5],[1 2 3 4 5], [1 2 3 4 5]};
bb = {[1 2 3],[1 3 4 5], [5]};

cc = cellfun(@setdiff, aa, bb, 'Uniform',false)
```